# Creating a video from array of UIImages in iOS runs out of memory

Tags: ios, swift, performance, memory, avfoundation

I'm currently working on a project where I need to generate a 20-second video from a full-screen SwiftUI animation.

Generating an array of UIImages was very simple. At 24fps, a 20 second video takes 480 images.

The problem I've encountered is during the rendering process. When the rendering begins, the memory consumption spikes, leading to a crash on my iPhone 15 Pro. It only works by reducing the duration to 10 seconds (240 images), although the memory still reached approximately 2GB before successfully exporting the video.

After that point, the memory is never released which leads me to believe there is some kind of leak somewhere.

I'm reaching out to the community for guidance on optimizing the performance of my code. If anyone can provide insights or suggestions to make the rendering process more efficient, I would greatly appreciate it.

This is the full code. You should be able to copy/paste to make it work:

```swift
import AVFoundation

class VideoRenderer {
    private let commandQueue: DispatchQueue
    private let fps: Int

    init(framesPerSecond: Int) {
        self.fps = framesPerSecond
        self.commandQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoRendererQueue")
    }

    func renderVideo(images: [UIImage], outputURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        guard !images.isEmpty else {
            completion(VideoRendererError.emptyImageArray)
            return
        }

        let width = Int(images[0].size.width)
        let height = Int(images[0].size.height)

        commandQueue.async {
            do {
                let videoWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: outputURL, fileType: .mp4)

                let videoSettings: [String: Any] = [
                    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                    AVVideoWidthKey: width,
                    AVVideoHeightKey: height,
                    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [
                        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: 6000000, // Adjust as needed
                        AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264MainAutoLevel,
                    ]
                ]

                let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoSettings)
                videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

                let adaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(
                    assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput,
                    sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil
                )

                guard videoWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput) else {
                    completion(VideoRendererError.failedToAddVideoInput)
                    return
                }

                videoWriter.add(videoWriterInput)

                let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(1), timescale: Int32(self.fps))

                videoWriter.startWriting()
                videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: .zero)

                self.commandQueue.async {
                    for (index, image) in images.enumerated() {
                        autoreleasepool {
                            guard let pixelBuffer = try? self.pixelBufferFromImage(image: image, width: width, height: height) else {
                                print("Failed to create pixel buffer for frame \(index).")
                                return
                            }

                            while !adaptor.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
                            }

                            let presentationTime = CMTimeMultiply(frameDuration, multiplier: Int32(index))
                            adaptor.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
                        }
                    }

                    videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
                    videoWriter.finishWriting {
                        completion(videoWriter.error)
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                completion(error)
            }
        }
    }

    private func pixelBufferFromImage(image: UIImage, width: Int, height: Int) throws -> CVPixelBuffer {
        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
        let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(
            kCFAllocatorDefault,
            width,
            height,
            kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
            nil,
            &pixelBuffer
        )

        guard status == kCVReturnSuccess, let buffer = pixelBuffer else {
            throw VideoRendererError.failedToCreatePixelBuffer
        }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        defer { CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0)) }

        let context = CIContext(options: nil)

        // Resize image to fit the frame
        let resizedImage = image.resize(targetSize: CGSize(width: width, height: height))

        context.render(
            CIImage(cgImage: resizedImage.cgImage!),
            to: buffer,
            bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height),
            colorSpace: nil
        )

        return buffer
    }
}

enum VideoRendererError: Error {
    case emptyImageArray
    case failedToAddVideoInput
    case failedToCreatePixelBuffer
}

// UIImage extension for resizing
extension UIImage {
    func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let size = self.size
        let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height
        let newSize = widthRatio > heightRatio ?
            CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio) :
            CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
        self.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
}
```

To use it, generate an array of UIImages and do the following:

```swift
var outputURL: URL {
  let videoFilename = "render"
  let videoFilenameExt = "mp4"
  let fileManager = FileManager.default
  if let tmpDirURL = try? fileManager.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true) {
            return tmpDirURL.appendingPathComponent(videoFilename).appendingPathExtension(videoFilenameExt)
  }
  fatalError("URLForDirectory() failed")
}

let renderer = VideoRenderer(framesPerSecond: Int(fps))
renderer.renderVideo(images: frames, outputURL: outputURL) { error in
  if let error { 
    // Something went wrong
    print(error)
  } else {
    // All good
    print("Video recorded at \(outputURL)")
  }
}
```